# Is there a way to check details on an expired domain?

Tags: domains

One of the companies I was working for had to shut down a couple of their projects with that the domains that they owned expired. Is there a way to prove that the domains existed and see a cached version of the site on a previous date?

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to check website history.

1) If you already know the domain name, then you can see it's history at [Web Archive](http://archive.org/web/)

2) You may also check your site on Google `site:expireddomain.com` and checkout whether it display any cache result or not.

You can even use [Domain Tools](http://research.domaintools.com/research/whois-history/) and [Who.is](https://who.is/domain-history/) website to check your domain history as well.

Comment: Also, is there a way to check when the expired domain was registered?

Comment: @CaptainBlack There are a number of sites which list expired domains that will list the _WBY_, which is the year of the WHOIS creation date, or the _ABY_, which is the first found date in `archive.org`. Other sites such as `domaintools.com` contain even more detailed domain history reports, but you might have to pay to access them.

Comment: I was looking for 2 things in my answer. The second part was answered by @Goyllo and the first part was answered by in the comment. Goyllo can edit his answer to include dan's comment or dan can create a new answer that includes both and I will accept that as the answer.

Comment: Answer updated, Thank dan for your kind suggestion :)